# Apache 2.4 whole URL rewrite https

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I have an Apache 2.4 configuration on my server, which is reached via the dns entries 
alpha.site.com and beta.site.com

I want the alpha.site.com to redirect seamlessly to the document root /this
and beta.site.com to redirect seamlessly to the document root /that

I suspect that this is done by using the rewrite rules of Apache in httpd.conf,
eg something like this

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule  "^https:\/\/alpha\.site\.com$" "https://alpha.site.com/this" [PT]
```

which doesn't seem to work. 
Are there any insights on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up following a different route to solve this by using Alias directives, one for each URL.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName alpha.site.com
Alias "/" "/this/"
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName beta.site.com
Alias "/" "/that/"
</VirtualHost>
```